# How to collect payments for the missed periods with the hard decline status?

Tags: commerce

Scenario: A user's credit card expires and he misses to pay his recurring monthly fee. Two months later he updates his credit card and because the license never expired the system picks it up and continues to successfully charge his card on file for consequent periods, but unfortunately not for the previous.

And it's not clear how to charge for the missed payments with the "Payment failed (hard decline)" status. Any suggestions?

Edit: I had to delete my own answer:

> It was not obvious for me that I needed to use Commerce Dunning module
>   to re-charge for the missed payments.

after trying the Commerce Dunning module, because unfortunately for hard declines it only sends notifications without attempting to re-charge for the missed period even if a customer updated his credit card. Per description on https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_dunning:

> If it was a hard decline that led to the failure, the customer needs
>   to update their credit card, so notifications regarding that are also
>   scheduled.

So unfortunately it is still not clear how to collect payments for the missed period.

Comment: After 6 month I am hitting the same issue. Unfortunately, no acceptable answer is given and it is not clear how to collect charges for the missed periods.

Answer (score 0):

If a customer has a hard decline, they'll need to log in and create a new stored payment option. They can create new stored payments via their account dashboard:

[image]

If memory serves, it should then be used by default.

Comment: Nick, thank you for your response, however as I stated above `even if a customer updated his credit card` the order for the missed period is never processed. Future periods are ok, but what about the missed ones?